# Autohotkey Capslock+Shif+Z

Tags: autohotkey

How to make an Autohotkey Command for following button combinations: CapsLock+Shift+Z returning Ź 
and 
CapsLock+z returning ź.

P.S. Searching in the web returns nothing for may case.

Comment: you should improve your web searching skills. Start here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

Answer (score 0):

- This AutoHotkey script attempts to make <kbd>CapsLock+Shift+Z</kbd> return Ź and <kbd>CapsLock+Z</kbd> return ź.
- Testing showed good functionality, with one exception: I found that if I hold <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> down first, then <kbd>Shift+Z</kbd>, there may be a delay in the keys firing.
  This is because keyboards can't always handle *any* key combination smoothly,
  many keyboards are not designed to utilise <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as a modifier key.

-

```
#CapsLock:: ;win+capslock - an alternative hotkey for capslock
SetStoreCapslockMode, Off
SendInput {CapsLock}
SetStoreCapslockMode, On
JEE_RetX()

CapsLock::
if GetKeyState("z", "p")
if GetKeyState("Shift", "p")
SendInput Ź
else
SendInput ź
Return

+CapsLock::
if GetKeyState("z", "p")
SendInput Ź
Return

CapsLock & z::
if GetKeyState("Shift", "p")
SendInput Ź
else
SendInput ź
Return

+z::
if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "p")
SendInput Ź
else
SendInput Z
Return
```